# Specific Dictionary Element as CommandParameter

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

```
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction CommandParameter="{}" Command="{Binding ChangeViewModelCommand}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

In the ViewModel, itself, I have a `Dictionary<string, IViewModel>` defined which contains a reference to every `ViewModel` of the application. The property is `ApplicationViewModels`. From this command, is it possible to access a specific `Dictionary` entry of `ApplicationViewModels`?

The goal is to pass an already instantiated instance to the command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can and it's very simple to do so:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction CommandParameter="{Binding ApplicationViewModels[DictKey]}" Command="{Binding ChangeViewModelCommand}"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Where DictKey is the key of the viewmodel you're trying to pass.